# what is in the HTML5 toDataURL?

Tags: html5-canvas

Simple question really but cant seem to find an answer...

the toDataURL() method retrieves a block of data. but what is it?

Is it memory addresses or pixel information.

If its pixel information is there a schema that describes it.

Answer (score 1):

How silly do I feel

Just looked on wiki to find this link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

So its a Base64 encoding of the image... I think!

Answer (score 0):

If you take the String that is returned by `toDataURL()` and insert  it into your browsers adress bar and press enter, it will take you to the rendered image.

In other words:
`toDataURL()` provides a REST-like way to access the image as a resource.